# VAT Number HTML5 Form Pattern

Tags: html, regex, forms

So I've got to validate European VAT numbers when a user registers.
I've got the following pattern set:

```
^((AT)?U[0-9]{8}|(BE)?0[0-9]{9}|(BG)?[0-9]{9,10}|(CY)?[0-9]{8}L|(CZ)?[0-9]{8,10}|(DE)?[0-9]{9}|(DK)?[0-9]{8}|(EE)?[0-9]{9}|(EL|GR)?[0-9]{9}|(ES)?[0-9A-Z][0-9]{7}[0-9A-Z]|(FI)?[0-9]{8}|(FR)?[0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}|(GB)?([0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})|(HU)?[0-9]{8}|(IE)?[0-9]S[0-9]{5}L|(IT)?[0-9]{11}|(LT)?([0-9]{9}|[0-9]{12})|(LU)?[0-9]{8}|(LV)?[0-9]{11}|(MT)?[0-9]{8}|(NL)?[0-9]{9}B[0-9]{2}|(PL)?[0-9]{10}|(PT)?[0-9]{9}|(RO)?[0-9]{2,10}|(SE)?[0-9]{12}|(SI)?[0-9]{8}|(SK)?[0-9]{10})$
```

And I'm also clarifying it in the placeholder/title that they need to: Enter VAT Number: CC0123456789 which includes the CC (Country Code).

However clients still don't seem to understand this and still fill in the VAT number without the Country Code and the pattern doesn't seem to check this if a country code has been entered.

So for example I want people to always enter the country code and their vat number accordingly. As it is now you can either enter BE0123456789 or 0123456789 but the latter is something I specifically do not want.

Is there a way to have the above pattern to force use the Country Code?

Thanks in advance for further information.

Edit: Solution found and optimised code further on for all Europe Countries and some non Europe ones as well!

```
^(SM[0-9]{5}|(IS|CH)[0-9]{6}|(ATU|DK|FI|LU|MT|SI|HU)[0-9]{8}|(BE0|DE|EE|EL|GR|PT|УНП|IL|RS|UZ)[0-9]{9}|(PL|SK|TR|UA)[0-9]{10}|(AU|IT|LV|HR)[0-9]{11}|(SE|PH)[0-9]{12}|(CA|ID)[0-9]{15}|BG[0-9]{9,10}|CY[0-9]{8}L|CZ[0-9]{8,10}|ES[0-9A-Z][0-9]{7}[0-9A-Z]|FR[0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}|GB([0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})|IE[0-9]S[0-9]{5}L|LT([0-9]{9,12}|[0-9]{12})|NL[0-9]{9}B[0-9]{2}|RO[0-9]{2,10}|(ALK|ALJ)[0-9]{8}L|IN[0-9]{11}(V|C)|NO[0-9]{9}MVA|RU[0-9]{10,12}|CHE[0-9]{9}(TVA|MWST|IVA))$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all you need is to make the country code parts *obligatory*.

In your pattern, the first (and all other instances of a country code) `(AT)?` is inside an optional group. `(...)` is a capturing group that "groups" a sequence of chars. Here, `AT`. The `?` quantifier means `AT` char sequence can appear 1 or 0 times. Remove `(` and `)?` and `AT` will be required exactly once.

In `(EL|GR)?`, you just need to remove the `?` quantifier since you still need a group to match either of the alternatives, `EL` or `GR`.

Use

```
^(ATU[0-9]{8}|BE0[0-9]{9}|BG[0-9]{9,10}|CY[0-9]{8}L|CZ[0-9]{8,10}|DE[0-9]{9}|DK[0-9]{8}|EE[0-9]{9}|(EL|GR)[0-9]{9}|ES[0-9A-Z][0-9]{7}[0-9A-Z]|FI[0-9]{8}|FR[0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}|GB([0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})|HU[0-9]{8}|IE[0-9]S[0-9]{5}L|IT[0-9]{11}|LT([0-9]{9}|[0-9]{12})|LU[0-9]{8}|LV[0-9]{11}|MT[0-9]{8}|NL[0-9]{9}B[0-9]{2}|PL[0-9]{10}|PT[0-9]{9}|RO[0-9]{2,10}|SE[0-9]{12}|SI[0-9]{8}|SK[0-9]{10})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ArYl0U/1).

Comment: Thanks a bunch Wiktor! Pretty much did the trick and that handy RegEx demo made me also see how it actually worked, definitely keeping that site for future reference. I've also optimised the pattern to have more groups bundled (saving bytes) which I will post in my main post.

Thanks a bunch for the assistance!